# How to connect a VB.NET .XML file with an android application

Tags: android, xml

I created an `.XML` file in `VB.NET` which retrieves data from a MSsql database.

Now I want to connect this `.XML` file with an Android application but I want the first column
to be connected with a "spinner" and the rest of the columns will be displayed after choosing
a value from the "spinner".

I hope the idea is clear enough.

Comment: What have you actually tried in "an Android application"?

Comment: I still didn't try anything because am new to android so no idea how to start even though i have a little background about java

Comment: A XML file is a XML file, regardless of how or where it was created. If the syntax is correct, of course, but that has nothing to do with where it comes from.